# How to properly update the PHP version on my mac OSX

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am basically trying to install PHP Swift Mailer into my project. Swift Mailer requires PHP 7 and higher and mine is PHP 5.6.

So i decided to upgrade PHP and i followed the advice of these guys https://php-osx.liip.ch/
Installation seemed okay, but the Sift Mailer installation fails with an error of "you do not have the required PHP version to do this installation". And when i run the command php -version i still see i have PHP version 5.6

How can i resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What keeps you from installing an older version of SwiftMailer, compatible with tour PHP version? And how is this related to Apache after all?

Comment: Def duplicate, but checkout Brew. https://brew.sh/

Comment: @Nico Haase thanks, i didn't know older Swift Mailer versions that work will older PHP versions. I'm new to Swift Mailer and on the landing page it said "System Requirements
Swift Mailer requires PHP 7.0 or higher (proc_* functions must be available)."

Comment: Swiftmailer started more than ten years ago, when nobody thought about something like PHP 7 ;)

Comment: Agreed. I have removed the Apache tag-i was just trying to attract people who are good at PHP installation/updates :)  
 Well i have installed an older version and now emails are being sent. My other question is why does a library like Swift Mailer successfully send emails from a localhost server while the built-in mail() function cannot. I suppose that should be a new question. I need to understand why. My mail() script also failed to send emails on my GoDaddy domain-i have a heck of a task rewriting those scripts to use Swift Mailer

Answer (score 0):

If you like I have a full LAMP stack built on Docker which I use with Mac.

You need:

- git
- VirtualBox
- Docker

The first time you use Docker, you need to set up the Base VM:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Once up and running, you do this for every terminal tab you want to run docker on:

```
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

Then you git clone https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp and cd into the folder.

Start your new server up!

```
docker-compose up
```

You now have:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.3
- Lots of PHP modules
- MariaDb
- MailHog
- XDebug
- Imagemagick
- Composer
- VirtualHost awesome.scot
- self signed SSL certificate

Oh yeah, add the VirtualHost to `/etc/hosts` on your Mac. Check the ip of your VM, it should be `192.168.99.100` but you can confirm by typing `docker-machine env`

Now you can browse to `https://awesome.scot` and you have a placeholder index.php

To SSH into your VM (to run Composer etc), type the following:

```
docker-compose exec php /bin/bash
```

The great thing is, this setup works on Mac, Windows, and Linux, and you will always have a consistent environment!

When finished devving, CMD-C to quit the server, and clean up with `docker-compose down`. Good luck and have fun!